# What kind of words can be used with とうとう、ついに、やっと、ようやく、いよいよ？

Tags: word-choice, words, syntax, adverbs, sentence

I'm currently studying more about とうとう、やっと、ついに、ようやく。Beside the same meaning 'finally', how about kind of words that can be used together with them? 
How about their structure?

Like ます形、る形、られる、い形容詞、な形容詞、or something like that. If you know something about it please help me, thank you :)

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/15293/meaning/m0u/, http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/15295/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 1):

They can be used together with verbs like ついに来た and some nouns. However in the case of nouns, a verb is generally omitted like やっと夏だ(it means やっと夏が来た or やっと夏になった).

I feel they, which are used together with an adjective, are unnatural but they can be used with an adjective　+ なる like やっと静かになる.